# Client side model validation for Sequelize Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, client-side

What's the best approach for doing client side validation of sequelize models?

I would like to pass the model definition objects to the client and have it interpret the constraints there. For example sequelize-restful already has a describe function that can send these constraints, I just haven't found a library that can interpret them.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

Given that the restful url format is generally domain.com/../{element}/{id} most javascript client side MVC/MV* frameworks such as backbone, ember.js, knockout, angular?, etc... would at least fit well for basic requires.

This API is specified https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-restful
and is clearly similar to the default formats supported in popular frameworks, such as, http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url